# Date input field format is ignored on reload in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have the following model in my ASP.NET Core 3.0 project:

```
class DataModel
{
  public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
  public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}  
}
```

I use the following Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(DataModel dataModel = null)
{
  actualDataModel = new DataModel { StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7), EndDate = DateTime.Today };
  if (dataModel.StartDate != DateTime.MinValue)
  {
    actualDataModel.StartDate = dataModel.StartDate;
    actualDataModel.EndDate = dataModel.EndDate;
  }
  return View(actualDataModel);
}
```

In the view, I have this field:

```
<input asp-for="StartDate" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" type="date" />
```

On the first run, I see the proper date and this is how the source looks like:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The StartDate field is required." id="StartDate" name="StartDate" value="2019-10-30" />
```

When I refresh, I get empty *visual fields* with the following source:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" data-val="true" data-val-required="The StartDate field is required." id="StartDate" name="StartDate" value="10/30/2019 00:00:00" />
```

Why can't ASP.NET properly format dates? How should I force it?

Comment: I try your code and it does not change (still works well)when I press F5 to refresh.Have you tried in a new 3.0 mvc project to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @XingZou Maybe you tried with en-EN culture..as you can see, my date format is _not en-EN_, so, when it changes from _2019-10-30._ to _30/10/2019_, they are completely different formats. I didn't try with a brand new project as it is wrong in the current one.